# Accessing elements within a pointer of a struct inside another pointer to a struct

Tags: c++, c, pointers, struct

Just trying to learn how nested pointers to structs work. How would I access an element within a pointer of a struct within another pointer to a struct? Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>

typedef struct
{
  unsigned int            a;
  unsigned int            b;
  unsigned int            c;
} inner;

typedef struct
{
  unsigned int            d;
  unsigned int            e;
  inner * in;
} outer;

/* Function to use struct */
void test(outer * out)
{
  //Update the value of out->in->a.
  out->in->a = 5;
}

int main() {
  outer * out;
  test(out);

  std::cout << "My updated value: " << out->in->a << std::endl;
}
```

I get a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

Edit: Made changes based on suggestions.

```
#include <iostream>

typedef struct
{
    unsigned int            a;
    unsigned int            b;
    unsigned int            c;
} inner;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned int            d;
    unsigned int            e;
    inner * in = new inner();
} outer;

/* Function to use struct */
void test(outer * out)
{
    //Update the value of out->d.
    out->d = 3; 
    //Update the value of out->in->a.
    out->in->a = 5;
}

int main() {

    outer out; 
    outer* p = &out; 

    test(p);

    std::cout << "My updated value for d: " << p->d << std::endl;
    std::cout << "My updated value for a: " << p->in->a << std::endl;
}
```

I now get the correct values updated. However I have a warning now

"warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11"

```
inner * in = new inner();
```

How do I fix this warning?

Comment: your problem is you only have a pointer to `out`. You need to allocate the memory first.

Comment: this would still fail because `in` has no memory

Comment: Sorry, why do you have those typedefs again?

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with c++ and pointers first. Maybe look here for a bit http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/ To explain everything in this Stackoverflow question would be a bit too much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters C and C++ are different languages.

In any case you have to allocate the structures before accessing their elements throw pointers. Otherwise using uninitialized pointers or pointers that do not point to valid structures' objects results in undefined behavior of the program.

Here is a demonstrative C program that shows how to access elements of a structure using pointers

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
  unsigned int            a;
  unsigned int            b;
  unsigned int            c;
} inner;

typedef struct
{
  unsigned int            d;
  unsigned int            e;
  inner * in;
} outer;


int main( void ) 
{
    outer *out = malloc( sizeof( outer ) );

    if ( ( out != NULL ) && ( out->in = malloc( sizeof( inner ) ) ) )
    {
        out->in->a = 1;
        out->in->b = 2;
        out->in->c = 3;

        printf( "out->in = { a = %d, b = %d, c = %d }\n", out->in->a, out->in->b, out->in->c );

        free( out->in );
        free( out );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
out->in = { a = 1, b = 2, c = 3 }
```

In C++ the program can look like

```
#include <iostream>

typedef struct
{
  unsigned int            a;
  unsigned int            b;
  unsigned int            c;
} inner;

typedef struct
{
  unsigned int            d;
  unsigned int            e;
  inner * in;
} outer;

int main() 
{
    outer *out = new outer;

    out->in = new inner;

    out->in->a = 1;
    out->in->b = 2;
    out->in->c = 3;

    std::cout << "out->in = { a = " << out->in->a
              << ", b = " << out->in->b
              << ", c = " << out->in->c
              << " }" << std::endl;

    delete out->in;
    delete out;

    return 0;
}
```

Its output will be the same as shown above.

As for this function

```
void test(outer *out)
{
  //Update the value of out->in->a.
  out->in->a = 5;
}
```

then the both pointers `out` and `in` must point to valid objects of types `outer` and `inner`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `test()` function, `out` does not point to any *valid* memory location. Attempt to dereference that pointer will invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

So, you need to allocate memory to `out` in `main()` and pass that to `test()`.

**After that**, `out->in` also being a pointer, you need to allocate memory to that pointer also so that it points to a valid memory location. After you have ensured that **all** pointers point to valid memory location, you can go ahead dereferencing them.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters, you only have a pointer to out, which currently has no allocated memory: As @IgorTandetnik said, do this:

> `outer out; outer* p = &out; test(p);` You have an uninitialized pointer that isn't pointing to anything valid.

When test uses `out`, by dereferencing it, you basically Undefined behavior, as expected with dereferencing pointers not pointing to anything.

Next, you have the same problem for `in`, which also has no allocated memory. Fix that by allocating memory for `in`, which currently also causes Undefined Behavior, like before.

Also, I am confused why you have those `typedefs`, and yet tagged your question [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). If you are compiling with a c compiler, it makes sense, but otherwise, you don't need to prefix with `struct` in A c++ compiler, which already does it for you.

Comment: My main has that outer out and can pass out into the function. Accessing any elements outer struct works. But now how do I allocate memory for in?

I tried 
inner in; inner* q = &in;

Comment: `out->in = new inner()` in your `test()` function. Do this before other code

Answer (score 0):

derefencing pointers should come **after** some form of allocation.

inside your function `out->in->a = 5;` gets a declared_but_not_initilized pointer. you should have done before that something like `out = new outer();` but then only the `out` pointer could be defreferenced [actually it could be defreferenced  before but that would cause UB - bad], so now you shuold also allocate for the `in` pointer like so `out->in = new inner();` and that's it:

```
/* Function to use struct */
void test(outer * out)
{
  //Update the value of out->in->a.
  out->in = new inner();       // addition
  out->in->a = 5;
}

int main() {
  outer * out;
  out = new outer();   // addition

  test(out);

  std::cout << "My updated value: " << out->in->a << std::endl;
}
```

*Note: I used `new` because you used `#include <iostream>` meaning c++. If using C, please use `malloc` instead*

Comment: This works just like mine, however I get the following warning:
warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
       
inner * in = new inner();