# Segmentation Fault when access to a pointer of struct in struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

I have an issue with pointers to struct that have members that are pointers to struct too.

Browsing the suggested similar questions I found out this:

[Accessing elements within a pointer of a struct inside another pointer to a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39252543/accessing-elements-within-a-pointer-of-a-struct-inside-another-pointer-to-a-struct)

where people suggest to pay attention to allocation memory of the structure.

I think this is done correctly in my code.

```
typedef struct {
  int id_vec;
  float *vec_value;
} Vector;

typedef struct cluster{
  int id_cluster;
  float *centroid;
  Vector *patternInCluster; 
} Cluster;

int main(void){
  Cluster *cluster_ptr= malloc(3 * sizeof(Cluster));
  if (cluster_ptr==NULL){
    printf("NULL");
  }
  cluster_ptr->patternInCluster=malloc(2 * sizeof(Vector *));
  if (cluster_ptr->patternInCluster==NULL){
    printf("NULL");
    cluster_ptr->patternInCluster=NULL;
  }

  float p1[3]={0.0f,1.0f,2.0f};
  Vector *somePattern=malloc(2 * sizeof(Vector));
  somePattern[0].id_vec=1;
  somePattern[0].vec_value=p1;
  somePattern[1].id_vec=2;
  somePattern[1].vec_value=p1;
}
```

Then I expect that this statement works:

`cluster_ptr[1].patternInCluster[1]=somePattern[1];`

But it compiles and produces a Segmentation Fault.

Unexpectedly, the following statement doesn't get errors:

`cluster_ptr[0].patternInCluster[1]=somePattern[1];`

and a test show me correct result(somePattern[1] id and value)

I tried to debug with gdb but I only can see this:

`Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00005555555547fe in main () at test_struct.c:36
36      cluster_ptr[1].patternInCluster[1]=somePattern[1];`

Am I missing some allocation mistakes?

Comment: OT: regarding: `typedef struct {
  int id_vec;
  float *vec_value;
} Vector;`  1) always include a 'tag' name because most debuggers use the 'tag' name to access the individual fields of the struct.  2) for flexibility, separate the definition of the struct from a typedef for that struct

Comment: The posted code does not compile!  So how you expect us to be able to reproduce the problem and then help you to debug it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is NOT accessing the pointer inside the struct. Your problem is how you are using `malloc()`.

When you have one pointer, you malloc only once:

```
int *pointer = (int* )malloc(sizeof(int));
*pointer = 1;
printf("*pointer:%d\n", *pointer);
```

When you have pointer-to-pointer, you malloc() once for the `**pointer_to_pointer`, but you also have to malloc() once for the `*pointer_to_pointer`:

```
int** pointer_to_pointer = (int** )malloc(sizeof(int*));
*pointer_to_pointer = (int* )malloc(sizeof(int));
**pointer_to_pointer = 2;
printf("**pointer:%d\n", **pointer_to_pointer);
```

And if you have more than one pointer, at the location pointed to by `**pointer_to_pointer`, you need a `for` loop to assign memory to every one of those `*pointer_to_pointer`s.

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    *(pointer_to_pointer + i*sizeof(int)) = (int* )malloc(sizeof(int));
}
**(pointer_to_pointer + sizeof(int)) = 3;
**(pointer_to_pointer + 2UL*sizeof(int)) = 4;
printf("**(pointer_to_pointer + sizeof(int):%d\n", **(pointer_to_pointer + sizeof(int)));
printf("**(pointer_to_pointer + 2UL*sizeof(int):%d\n", **(pointer_to_pointer + 2UL*sizeof(int)));
```

You are mistaken to think that `Cluster *cluster_ptr= malloc(3 * sizeof(Cluster));` will automatically/magically assign memory for `Cluster[0]` and `Cluster[1]` and `Cluster[2]`.

Your statement actually assigns memory only for `Cluster[0]`, but big enough for 3 `Cluster`s.

So the **the modified code** will look like this:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct {
    int id_vec;
    float *vec_value;
} Vector;

typedef struct cluster{
    int id_cluster;
    float *centroid;
    Vector **patternInCluster;
} Cluster;

int main(void){

    Cluster **cluster_ptr = (Cluster **)malloc(sizeof(Cluster*));
    for (long unsigned int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cluster_ptr[i] = (Cluster *)malloc(sizeof(Cluster));
        if (cluster_ptr[i]==NULL){
            printf("NULL");
        }

        cluster_ptr[i]->patternInCluster = (Vector **) malloc(sizeof(Vector*));
        for (long unsigned int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            (*cluster_ptr)->patternInCluster[j] = (Vector *) malloc(sizeof(Vector));
            if ((*cluster_ptr)->patternInCluster[j]==NULL){
                printf("NULL");
                (*cluster_ptr)->patternInCluster[j]=NULL;
            }
        }
    }



    float p1[3]={0.0f,1.0f,2.0f};
    Vector *somePattern= (Vector *) malloc(sizeof(Vector));
    somePattern[0].id_vec=1;
    somePattern[0].vec_value=p1;
    somePattern[1].id_vec=2;
    somePattern[1].vec_value=p1;

    cluster_ptr[1]->patternInCluster[1] = &somePattern[0];
    cluster_ptr[0]->patternInCluster[1] = &somePattern[1];
    cluster_ptr[1]->patternInCluster[0] = &somePattern[1];
    cluster_ptr[2]->patternInCluster[1] = &somePattern[0];

    printf("%d\n", cluster_ptr[1]->patternInCluster[1]->id_vec);
    printf("%d\n", cluster_ptr[0]->patternInCluster[1]->id_vec);
    printf("%d\n", cluster_ptr[1]->patternInCluster[0]->id_vec);
    printf("%d\n", cluster_ptr[2]->patternInCluster[1]->id_vec);

    return 0;
}
```

- On my system, I just compiled and it builds and runs error-free.

Comment: Thank you very much for the nice explanation. In the code, you declare cluster_ptr has `**Cluster` but this sounds weird to me, because I want it to point to a "vector" of struct.  As you said, I misunderstood that `Cluster *cluster_ptr= malloc(3 * sizeof(Cluster))` allocate enough memory for 3 pointer to struct, while it is only giving that space to `cluster_ptr[0]. Then why change the type of `Cluster *` to `Cluster **` when I can just allocate memory for each `*cluster_ptr[i].patternInCluster` in a loop?

Comment: @LucaJungla, you can try removing the `**` from the `Cluster` pointer and then replace all `.` with `->` and then run the program and see if it produces the right output. (Hint: It does not.)

Comment: it is not what I mean `for(i=0;i<k;i++) { cluster_ptr[i].patternInCluster=malloc(2 * sizeof(Vector *))}` then all this assignment :`cluster_ptr[0].patternInCluster[0]=somePattern[0]; cluster_ptr[1].patternInCluster[0]=somePattern[1]; etc...` works and print the right value

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're not populating things fully.

This line

```
cluster_ptr->patternInCluster=malloc(2 * sizeof(Vector *));
```

is the same as saying

```
cluster_ptr[0].patternInCluster=malloc(2 * sizeof(Vector *));
```

and really given that `cluster_ptr` has been allocated as 3 `Cluster` it would be more clearer in your code to do the latter.

Since `cluster_ptr[1].patternInCluster` hasn't been given a value, trying to dereference it will lead to undefined behaviour but more likely will result in a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

You do not allocate enough memory:

```
cluster_ptr->patternInCluster=malloc(2 * sizeof(Vector *));
```

With `patternInCluster` being of type `Vector *`, you should allocate memory to hold elements of type `Vector`, not `Vector*`.

```
cluster_ptr->patternInCluster=malloc(2 * sizeof(Vector));
```

Comment: I think this is true, but doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: There are too many problems to solve them all at once. Given that your struct is larger than 1 pointer you access memory that you don't own. It's always hard to get all issues if there are multiple in a question.